# Android Studio WebView "Expecting Member Declaration" with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-webview

Hi I just started using Android Studio and am trying to write a webView application. I followed android's tutorial on how to do so but for some reason it say the error "Expecting Member Declaration" on line 9 of MainActivity.kt Here is that file

```
package com.lowmap.lowmap

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

And here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help! I've been trying to figure out whats going on for hours but I'm just starting out with kotlin and android development.

Answer (score 1):

Please move your code to `onCreate` method of `MainActivity` class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com")
    }
}
```

Access to the activity's views must be done after `setContentView(...)` method is called.